# Minesweeper implementation in C++

Tags: c++, object-oriented

I have implemented minesweeper in C++. You can get a box by entering the coordinates -*row number, then column*; starting from 0- of said box (eg: "0 0"); you can mark a box as a bomb by adding the prefix *"mark"* (eg: "mark 0 0"); you can unflag a box by adding the prefix *"unmark"* (eg: "unmark 0 0"). The game ends when *all non-bomb boxes have been checked* & *all bombs have been marked*. Any feedback/ideas on how to improve my code would be very much appreciated.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"

int main()
{
    Game* g = new Game(16, 40);
    g->playGame();
    return 0;
}
```

**Game.h**

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "Grid.h"

#include <string>

class Game
{
    private:
        Grid* grid;
        int** closedSet;
        int len;
        int foundNum, closedSetSize;

    public:
        Game(int n, int b);
        ~Game();
        void printClosedSet();
        void playGame();

    private:
        void clearSpace(int n, int m);
};

#endif // GAME_H
```

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"

#include <queue>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

Game::Game(int n, int b) : foundNum(0), closedSetSize(0) {
    grid = new Grid(n, b);

    len = grid->getSize();
    closedSet = new int*[len];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        closedSet[i] = new int[len];
        std::memset(closedSet[i], 0, len * sizeof(int));
    }
}

Game::~Game() {
    delete grid;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        delete[] closedSet[i];
    delete[] closedSet;
}

void Game::printClosedSet() {
    std::cout << "    ";
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        std::cout << std::setw(3) << i;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    ";
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        std::cout << "---";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        std::cout << std::setw(3) << i << "|";
        for(int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            if(closedSet[i][j] == 1) {
                std::cout << std::setw(3) << grid->getNum(i, j);
            } else if(closedSet[i][j] == 0) {
                std::cout << std::setw(3) << "-";
            } else std::cout << std::setw(3) << "*";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void Game::playGame() {
    std::string s;
    int n, m;
    while(true) {
        printClosedSet();
        std::cin >> s;
        if((s.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == std::string::npos) && ((std::stoi(s) <= len-1) && (std::stoi(s) >= 0)))  {
            n = std::stoi(s);
            s = "placeholder";
            while(s.find_first_not_of("0123456789") != std::string::npos) {
                std::cin >> s;
                if((s.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == std::string::npos) &&
                   ((std::stoi(s) > len-1) || (std::stoi(s) < 0))) s = "placeholder";
            }
            m = std::stoi(s);
            if(closedSet[n][m] == 0) {
                if(grid->getNum(n, m) < 0) {
                    grid->printBombs(closedSet);
                    std::cout << "YOU HAVE LOST" << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
                clearSpace(n, m);
            }
        } else if (s == "mark" || s == "unmark"){
            std::string temp = "placeholder";
            while(temp.find_first_not_of("0123456789") != std::string::npos) {
                std::cin >> temp;
                if((temp.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == std::string::npos) &&
                   (std::stoi(temp) > len-1)) temp = "placeholder";
            }
            n = std::stoi(temp);
            temp = "placeholder";
            while(temp.find_first_not_of("0123456789") != std::string::npos) {
                std::cin >> temp;
                if((temp.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == std::string::npos) &&
                   (std::stoi(temp) > len-1)) temp = "placeholder";
            }
            m = std::stoi(temp);
            if((s == "mark") && (closedSet[n][m] == 0)) {
                closedSet[n][m] = 3;
                if(grid->getNum(n, m) < 0) ++foundNum;
            } else if((s == "unmark") && (closedSet[n][m] == 3)) {
                closedSet[n][m] = 0;
                if(grid->getNum(n, m) < 0) --foundNum;
            }
        } else continue;
        if((grid->getBombNum() == foundNum) && (closedSetSize == len*len - grid->getBombNum())) {
            printClosedSet();
            std::cout << "YOU HAVE WON" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    grid->clearGrid();
    grid->generateGrid();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        std::memset(closedSet[i], 0, len * sizeof(int));
    foundNum = 0;
    closedSetSize = 0;
}

void Game::clearSpace(int n, int m) {
    std::queue<std::pair<int, int>> q;
    if(closedSet[n][m] == 0) ++closedSetSize;
    closedSet[n][m] = 1;
    if(grid->getNum(n, m) == 0) q.push(std::make_pair(n, m));
    while(!q.empty()) {
        n = q.front().first;
        m = q.front().second;
        closedSet[n][m] = 1;
        if((n < len-1) && (closedSet[n+1][m] == 0)) {
            if(grid->getNum(n+1, m) == 0)
                q.push(std::make_pair(n+1, m));
            closedSet[n+1][m] = 1;
            ++closedSetSize;
        }

        if((n < len-1) && (m < len-1) && (closedSet[n+1][m+1] == 0)) {
            if(grid->getNum(n+1, m+1) == 0)
                q.push(std::make_pair(n+1, m+1));
            closedSet[n+1][m+1] = 1;
            ++closedSetSize;
        }

        if((n < len-1) && (m > 0)  && (closedSet[n+1][m-1] == 0)) {
            if(grid->getNum(n+1, m-1) == 0)
                q.push(std::make_pair(n+1, m-1));
            closedSet[n+1][m-1] = 1;
            ++closedSetSize;
        }

        if((m < len-1) && (closedSet[n][m+1] == 0)) {
            if(grid->getNum(n, m+1) == 0)
                q.push(std::make_pair(n, m+1));
            closedSet[n][m+1] = 1;
            ++closedSetSize;
        }

        if((n > 0) && (closedSet[n-1][m] == 0)) {
            if(grid->getNum(n-1, m) == 0)
                q.push(std::make_pair(n-1, m));
            closedSet[n-1][m] = 1;
            ++closedSetSize;
        }

        if((n > 0) && (m < len-1) && (closedSet[n-1][m+1] == 0)) {
            if(grid->getNum(n-1, m+1) == 0)
                q.push(std::make_pair(n-1, m+1));
            closedSet[n-1][m+1] = 1;
            ++closedSetSize;
        }

        if((n > 0) && (m > 0)  && (closedSet[n-1][m-1] == 0)) {
            if(grid->getNum(n-1, m-1) == 0)
                q.push(std::make_pair(n-1, m-1));
            closedSet[n-1][m-1] = 1;
            ++closedSetSize;
        }

        if((m > 0)  && (closedSet[n][m-1] == 0)) {
            if(grid->getNum(n, m-1) == 0)
                q.push(std::make_pair(n, m-1));
            closedSet[n][m-1] = 1;
            ++closedSetSize;
        }
        q.pop();
    }
}
```

**Grid.h**

```
#ifndef GRID_H
#define GRID_H

#include <vector>

class Grid
{
    private:
        int** grid;
        int len;
        int bombNum;
        std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> s;

    public:
        Grid(int n, int b);
        ~Grid();
        void printBombs(int** closedSet);
        void generateGrid();
        void clearGrid();
        int getNum(int n, int m) {return grid[n][m];}
        int getSize() {return len;}
        int getBombNum() {return bombNum;}
};

#endif // GRID_H
```

**Grid.cpp**

```
#include "Grid.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <iomanip>

Grid::Grid(int n, int b) : len(n), bombNum(b) {
    grid = new int*[len];

    s.reserve(len);

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < len; j++)
            s.push_back(std::make_pair(i, j));
        grid[i] = new int[len];
        std::memset(grid[i], 0, len * sizeof(int));
    }
    generateGrid();
}

Grid::~Grid() {
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        delete[] grid[i];
    delete[] grid;
}

void Grid::printBombs(int** closedSet) {
    std::cout << "    ";
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        std::cout << std::setw(3) << i;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    ";
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        std::cout << "---";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        std::cout << std::setw(3) << i << "|";
        for(int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            if(grid[i][j] < 0) {
                std::cout << std::setw(3) << "X";
            } else if(closedSet[i][j] == 1) {
                std::cout << std::setw(3) << grid[i][j];
            } else std::cout << std::setw(3) << "-";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void Grid::generateGrid() {
    shuffle(s.begin(),
        s.end(),
        std::default_random_engine(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()));

    for(int i = 0; i < bombNum; i++) {
        int randRow = s[i].first;
        int randCol = s[i].second;
        grid[randRow][randCol] = -1;
        if(randRow > 0) {
            if(grid[randRow-1][randCol] >= 0)
                ++grid[randRow-1][randCol];

            if((randCol > 0) && (grid[randRow-1][randCol-1] >= 0))
                ++grid[randRow-1][randCol-1];

            if((randCol < len-1) && (grid[randRow-1][randCol+1] >= 0))
                ++grid[randRow-1][randCol+1];
        }
        if(randRow < len-1) {
            if(grid[randRow+1][randCol] >= 0)
                ++grid[randRow+1][randCol];

            if((randCol > 0) && (grid[randRow+1][randCol-1] >= 0))
                ++grid[randRow+1][randCol-1];

            if((randCol < len-1) && (grid[randRow+1][randCol+1] >= 0))
                ++grid[randRow+1][randCol+1];
        }
        if((randCol > 0) && (grid[randRow][randCol-1] >= 0))
            ++grid[randRow][randCol-1];

        if((randCol < len-1) && (grid[randRow][randCol+1] >= 0))
            ++grid[randRow][randCol+1];
    }
}

void Grid::clearGrid() {
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < len; j++)
            grid[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Unnecessary memory allocations

You are using `new` and `delete` in many places where it is not necessary to do any memory allocations. Starting in `main()`, you can just write:

```
Game g(16, 40);
g.playGame();
```

Apart from slightly less typing, this also prevents the inevitable memory leak when you forget to `delete` what you just allocated.

The same goes for `Game::grid`, this doesn't have to be a pointer, it can be a regular member variable of `Game`.

## Let STL containers manage memory for you

In those cases where you do need to allocate memory, try to avoid using manual `new` and `delete`. In particular, for arrays of which you don't know the size up front, you can use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). It will automatically allocate and deallocate memory for you. If you have a two-dimensional array, you could make a vector of vectors, like so:

```
class Grid
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid;
    ...
};

Grid::Grid(int n, int b): grid(n, std::vector<int>(n)), ... {
    ...
}
```

However, that brings me to the following:

## Allocate a single array/vector for all elements of a 2D grid

Vectors of vectors, or dynamically allocated arrays of dynamically allocated arrays as you did in your code, are not efficient. To get to a certain element, the CPU would have to follow two pointers, which is inefficient. However, CPUs nowadays are great at multiplications and additions, so it is actually faster to allocate a 1D vector, and calculate yourself how to position 2D elements in it. For example:

```
class Grid
{
    std::vector<int> grid;
};
...
Grid::Grid(int n, int b): grid(n * n), ... {
    ...
}
...
void Grid::printBombs(...) {
    ...
    if (grid[i * len + j] < 0)
       ...
}
```

To avoid having to write that formula all the time, consider making a member function that takes the row and column position, and returns a reference to the desired grid element:

```
int& Grid::gridAt(int row, int col) {
    return grid[row * len + col];
}
```

Then you can just write:

```
if (gridAt(i, j) < 0)
    ...
```

Once you have a one-dimensional vector, some other things become easier as well. For example,

## Make use of STL algorithms

If you use STL containers, [STL algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) can now be used as well. For example, to clear the grid you can use [`std::fill()][3]`:

```
void Grid::clearGrid() {
    std::fill(grid.begin(), grid.end(), 0);
}
```

Think of `std::fill()` and [`std::fill_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) as C++'s version of C's `memset()`, and there's [`std::copy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) and [`std::copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) to replace `memcpy()`, but the algorithms can do much more than that, saving you the trouble of having to implement them yourself. To get more familiar with them, I recommend you read or watch [The World Map of C++ STL Algorithms](https://www.fluentcpp.com/getthemap/).

## Simplify parsing the input

Parsing the input is a bit complicated in your code, mainly because you either allow coordinates without any prefix, or coordinates with a prefix to be entered. Because you can't be sure if the first thing you read is going to be a number or a prefix, you have to read it as a `std::string`, check what it is, then use `std::stoi()` to convert it to a number if necessary. If you would change the way you read the input such that you always have to prefix the coordinates, and use the prefix "reveal" or "get" to reveal what is on a given grid position, you can greatly simplify parsing the input:

```
while (true) {
    printClosedSet();

    std::string command;
    int row;
    int col;

    std::cin >> command >> row >> col;

    if (command == "reveal") {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

## Consider using `emplace()` instead of `push()` where possible

Many containers have both `push()` and `emplace()` functions. The latter is sometimes more efficient and convenient. In particular, it reserves room for the new element and constructs it in place, and the arguments to `emplace()` are passed to the constructor of the value type of the container. This allows you to write:

```
std::queue<std::pair<int, int>> q;
...
q.emplace(n, m);
```

Note how you no longer need to use `std::make_pair()`.

## Create a `struct Cell`

You are actually keeping track of the state of each location on the board using two grids; one is `grid` and the other `closedSet`. It's also not so nice to overload `int`s to mean different things. Consider creating a `struct Cell` that holds *all* information of a grid cell:

```
struct Cell {
    int adjacentBombs;
    bool bomb;
    bool revealed;
    bool marked;
};
```

The you just need one datastructure to hold all information about the board:

```
std::vector<Cell> grid;
```

## Prefer `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`

Prefer using [`'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n); the latter is equivalent to the former, but also forces the output to be flushed, which is usually not necessary and has performance implications.

Comment: `sizeof(Cell)`  could be reduced easily, typically by half: Though `char` is overkill to count to 8. [Bitfields](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) would reduce to a single byte, but the more costly access probably makes it a net-negative.

Answer (score 3):

- Separate IO from business logic. From the game point of view it doesn't matter *how* the user asks to perform the action. With CLI it is "X Y", or "mark X Y", or wharever; with GUI it could be Click, Shift-Click, etc. The game doesn't care. What matters is the *action* to be performed.
- `generateGrid` seems buggy. Once the bomb is planted (that is, assigned `-1`) all the neighboring cells are incremented. If a bomb was already planted there, the cell's value is not `-1` anymore. Its bomb just disappears.
- `playGame` regenerates the grid *after* the game is finished. It doesn't feel right.
- The wall of `if`s in `clearSpace` shall be a loop over the neighboring cells.